# Can I do multi-computer and multi-monitor configuration with Synergy?

Tags: multiple-monitors, synergy

I've been asked to setup a demo room with multiple computers and monitors. We need to be able to use multiple monitors with a single PC in some cases. In other cases we need to switch between Mac and PC platforms. We would also like to be able to throw up slides or other information to screens which are not being used.

Is it possible to do this with [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Synergy is definitely the tool for this.

With Synergy you can control multiple computers (the clients) using the keyboard/mouse connected on one of them (the server). It doesn't matter if some of them have multiscreen setups. You can also control each of the clients with its own keyboard/mouse, if attached.

Some restrictions to consider

- currently, you cannot drag windows to different computers
- the computers should be on the same lan (or tunneled via ssh) as the protocol used by Synergy is insecure

Answer (score 1):

I can vouch for Input Director on Windows system. I tried Synergy first but couldn't get it to work on my windows 2000 machine. The stable release just hung the computer and the more recent release wouldn't start at all.

However, Input Director has worked perfectly, with hardly any difficulty setting up. The configuration interface is much easier than Synergy. Perfect for me!

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions to easier control your computers:

If you're running Windows only systems, then consider Input Director, which is more stable and has an easier GUI.

If you are using multiple operating systems, consider upgrading to Synergy+, which is a newer version of Synergy.

For an easier GUI version of Synergy, check out QSynergy. via Lifehacker.